# Same named struct one private and another public - how to access them seperate

Tags: ios, swift, access-modifiers

I have two files in in my project

*A.swift*

```
struct A {
    static let name = "Name"
}
```

*B.swift*

```
class ABC {
    private struct A {
       static let local = "local name"
    }

    func something() {
      // How to access A.name from here?
    }
}
```

Comment: And why not simply rename `private struct A` into something else, since it's the private struct in the same class where you have a problem?

Comment: A.swift is legacy code base[dont want to modify it], wondering if there could be some way to access the public one without putting into another class

Comment: renaming **private** struct is the safest thing to do, but you can also prefix the public one with project name, like the answer I linked mentions - sort of workaround really... not a good one

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name of your project/module is `MyProject`

```
func something() {
    print(MyProject.A.name)
}
```

Comment: What does QA mean? The namespace is grouped by modules. You can refer to structs/classes by the module prefix.

Comment: This is a shadowing (name hiding) issue. The answer is very nice.